# Reading a file line-wise

Tags: python

I have a file named `data.dat` in an S3 bucket, the contents of the file are in 3 lines

```
fruit
javaisnotafruit
xyq
```

I am reading from s3 this way

```
objectcontent = s3.get_object(Bucket="contents-bucket", Key=obj['Key'])
contentsins3 = objectcontent['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')
print(contentsins3)
```

When I do `print(contentsins3)` I am getting

```
fruit
javaisnotafruit
xyq
```

I have code for looping through the contents and read each line, how would I do that?

```
for i in contentsins3:
    print(i)
```

How would I get each line in S3 line by line?

Comment: This has nothing to do with s3 but about plain data parsing using python

Answer (score 2):

The body is [streaming](http://botocore.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/response.html), but when you do this you consume it all to EOF:

```
objectcontent['Body'].read()
```

So, don't do that.  Instead:

```
import encodings
stream = encodings.utf_8.StreamReader(objectcontent['Body'])
for line in stream:
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just plain string parsing, regardless of the storage.

So back to python, the object `contentsins3` contains the whole file data, together with the **`line break`**.

You can use splitlines() which will deal with `\n`, `\r\n`.

```
for i in contentsins3.splitlines():
    print(i)
```